# Why does my output gives a garbage value?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, structure

> I am learning structure and function and I'm trying to pass a pointer to structure as an argument. My code is to input student name,age and marks. This is my program

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>


 struct student {   
 char name[15];
 int age;
 double marks; 
 };

 void display(); 

 int main(){

 struct student *s1;

 s1 =(struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
 for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
 {
    printf("\nEnter details of student %d\n\n", i+1);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", s1->name);

    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1->age);

    printf("Enter marks: ");
    scanf("%f", &s1->marks);
}
display(&s1);       
}

void display(struct student *s1){ 

printf("\nName\tAge\tMarks\n");

for(int i = 0; i<2;i++ )
 {
    printf("Name: %s",s1->name);
    printf("\nAge: %d",s1->age);
    printf("\nMarks: %.2lf",s1->marks);
 }
}
```

> the code runs but it gave a wrong outputs and garbage value. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Variable `s1` is (already) of type `struct student *`. Thus, `&s1` is of type `struct student **`, which means that you need to call `display(s1)`, not `display(&s1)`. BTW, I'm not sure how this code even compiles.

Comment: BTW, not sure what you're hoping to achieve in that `for(int i=0; i<2; i++)` loop, as the second iteration "overrides" the first iteration.

Comment: `scanf("%f", &s1->marks);` ==> `scanf("%lf", &s1->marks);` for a `double` type.

Comment: @goodvibration im asking for 2 inputs, so that's why its  for(int i=0; i<2; i++)

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you i didn't notice that

Comment: Where do you want to store 2 inputs if you allocate memory for 1 struct?

Comment: `void display();` You should definitely add a parameter list to your function declaration. Otherwise your compiler is not able to detect if you pass garbage (wrong type) parameters.

Comment: @Gerhardh im sorry but i don't get what you mean, is it 2 inputs already in the for loop?.  Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: You store both sets of input in the same memory location. This destroys the values from first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax error. I have included documentation in the code below.

Also, you are overwriting the content of s1 everytime when you are prompting user to input. Test it with two different data for example (name: "alex", age: 19, mark: 100.0 and name: "jason", age: 22, mark: 100.0) your program will output only the later.

To solve this, I would suggest you to allocate your student pointer before looping so that you have two distinct memory for each student and you wont overwrite them in this case.

Basically, each student struct is treated as an array and instead of s1->name you will dereference them as s1[i].name

display function declaration

```
void display(struct student *s1);
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct student *s1;

    s1 =(struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student) * 2);  /* 2 = number of students */

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter details of student %d\n\n", i+1);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", s1[i].name);

        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &s1[i].age);

        printf("Enter marks: ");
        scanf("%lf", &s1[i].marks);   /* Instead of %f, it should be %lf */

    }

    display(s1);    /* Instead of &, it should be s1 */   

    /* Free heap memory */
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        free(s1);
        s1 = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Display function, you need some modification in your display function as well

```
void display(struct student *s1)
{ 
    int i;
    printf("\nName\tAge\tMarks\n");

    for(i = 0; i<2;i++ )
    {
        printf("%s\t",s1[i].name);
        printf("%d\t",s1[i].age);
        printf("%.2f\t",s1[i].marks);  /* Instead of %.2lf, it should be %.2f */
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Struct for student

```
struct student
{   
    char name[15];
    int age;
    double marks; 
};
```